# Flip effect in css animation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, keyframe, css-animations

I have made a flip card. But the rotate effect when you click on "press card" doesn't work

Can anyone help me?

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/sAtvD)

Comment: It works perfectly... what do you want to happen?

Comment: A rotate effect. The card flip without effect

Comment: You can find it here....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035643/jquery-how-to-do-a-flip-effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transitions are set up incorrectly, change it to

```
.cci-press-card__wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 380px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s ease;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cLilG)

Comment: Can it flip immediately after click instead of showing the `backface` then flip?

Comment: Is exactly that! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to follow some articles?

> http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/
>
> http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

Hope this can help!

Comment: This should had been a comment

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code. It was a tiny CSS change. You cannot animate CSS "transform" since it isn't a support property. You must instead write "all".

If you do that then you should have a working flip card :)

Enjoy.